# Joomla Extention to Delivery Personalize content based on keyword searched

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, joomla3.0, personalization

I have been a WordPress Developer for over 6 years now and finally stuck at one requirement.

One of my client has website that offers multiple IT services (i.e. Mobile Development, Web Development, Data Solutions etc.)

He wants to customize his home page based on the keyword his website was searched for. for Example of any of the user searches for "Mobile Development" in google and gets my clients website link and user clicks that link to visit the site, in that case my client wants to show only Mobile Development Services on home page so visitor looking for mobile development doesn't get anything else.

Same way if some user searched for Web Development in search engine and got my client site, then he will see only Web Development Content and links.

I am not able to get any plugin or method for WordPress that can serve personalize content based on keyword searched on search engine, somewhere i heard that there is extension in joomla that does it. Help me if that is possible.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The closest Joomla extension I can find for what you are asking is [Diginix Content Generation](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/landing-pages/diginix-content-generation) which costs US$30.

[Keyword Landing Page Generator](https://codecanyon.net/item/keyword-landing-page-generator/14141392) for US$17 is a similar type of plugin for WordPress.

These extensions tailor the content on the page dynamically based on search keywords. This is the preferred option to redirecting to a different url based on the search keywords which Google refers to as a [sneaky redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721217).